# Appium server is using deleted session Id in the successive test case even after creating a new session

Tags: android, ruby, appium

[Snapshot shows that Appium created a new session but as soon as the test starts, it switches back to older session id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRZe2.png)

I am running a cucumber based automation test suite using appium with ruby. There are 10 cucumber scenarios that should run in a series, one after the other and Appium initialization is done such that for each scenario, a new session is created and old one is destroyed.
The problem is when the first test completes, the android app I am automating closes, session is deleted and a new session is created - my app gets launched but as soon as the first step of my next test is reached, appium server starts using (as it shows on appium server logs) older session, the session that got deleted after test 1. Why is this happening? This causes a session not created or terminated error and my tests do not run.